# Google GeocodeAPI : "Rate Limited Dispatcher" error

Tags: java, geocoding, google-geocoder

I'm trying to use the Google Geocode API but I keep having the same error:
Exception in thread "Rate Limited Dispatcher" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.google.maps.internal.OkHttpPendingResult$1.onResponse(Lokhttp3/Response;)V

I don't understand what it means and I cannot find any explanation.

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey(...)
                .build();
        GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.geocode(context,myaddress).await();
        if (results.length > 0){
            answerGoogle= results[0].geometry.location;
            System.out.println(anwserGoogle);
        }
```

I have the error at line 4 (GeocodingResult[]...)
Could you help me?

Comment: I am getting the same problem.  Have you figured this out?  What environment are you running this in?

Comment: IO figured my problem out, I had mismatched libraries somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a missing shutdown() that lead to a saturation of threads.
You can also handle this differently if you are using spring boot, you can have more details here --> [Bug in google maps service](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/issues/261)